# Generate a list of installed PHP extensions

Tags: bash, files, php

My goal is to write an as simple as possible (but not more simple) that generates a list of currently installed PHP extensions (*.so files) that the user can simply copy/paste into their *php.ini*. It should be compatible at minimum with OS X and at least some major Linux distros (Ubuntu, Arch Linux, RHEL, etc.).

The expected output would look like:

```
extension=iconv.so
extension=mcrypt.so
...
```

So far, I have come up with this:

```
find `php-config --extension-dir` -name "*.so" | rev | cut -d / -f 1 | rev
```

It works well, but I feel it's a bit clumsy with all the string reversions. And, it only generates the extensions' names, it does not add the `extension=` prefix.

*I needed to use the reversions because the extension-dir might be of any depth, thus I cannot simply cut the string at a pre-determined path separator position. However, I know that if I cut it from the end at the first separator, I will get only the filename.*

Then I discovered the [`replace`](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/replace.htm) utility and wrote this, which is a perfect fit for my task, except it does not seem to be available on OS X and Arch Linux, the two systems I use most:

```
find `php-config --extension-dir` -name "*.so" | replace `php-config --extension-dir`/ 'extension='
```

Basically, I am looking for other creative (but simple) ways of completing this task. What other utilities could I use? Educate me! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
find "`php-config --extension-dir`" -name "*.so" | sed 's!^.*/!extension=!'
```

For each line, `sed` will match the longest string that starts at the beginning (`^`) and ends at `/`. It will always match everything up to and including the last `/`, because it is a greedy match, i.e., it will match everything *but* the filename. It then replaces that with `extension=`.

It ends up like so:

```
$ find "`php-config --extension-dir`" -name "*.so" | sed 's!^.*/!extension=!'
extension=pdo_pgsql.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=mysqlnd.so
extension=mysqli.so
extension=enchant.so
extension=pgsql.so
extension=mysql.so
extension=pdo_odbc.so
extension=odbc.so
extension=curl.so
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=sqlite3.so
```

which seems to be what you want.

`sed` ought to be available everywhere, because it's part of the POSIX standard.

Comment: Ah, awesome! I tried `sed`, too, but my approach was to use a substitution - something along the lines of `... | sed 's/\`php-config --extension-dir\`/extension=/g'` (this is probably wrong, but you get the picture), but it kept complaining due to the presence of `/` in the path. Let's see if others can come up with other ideas, but this is a good one!

Comment: @RobertRossmann: You can do it that way as well, but you'd have to use a different separation character than `/`. (In case you didn't know, that character can be anything except a command letter, as long as it's the same all three times and doesn't occur in the pattern unescaped.) E.g. ``sed "s~`php-config --extension-dir`/~extension=~"`` works the way you intended.

Comment: Huh, nice one. `sed`'s learning curve seems to me like a 90º uphill slope, but oh, the things you can do once on top...

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `GNU find` you can use `-printf` option

```
find `php-config --extension-dir` -name "*.so" -printf 'extension=%f\n'
```

Comment: This looks great, too! Unfortunately, Mac do not support the `-printf` option so I cannot use this for my purposes. But thanks for introducing me to that switch!